# Nuget package manager not working in visual studio 2019 version 16.7

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

Recently I have updated vs 2019 to Version 16.7. I have noticed that in this NuGet pointing to
https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json.now a single NuGet package not downloading from this NuGet source so I have changed the source to https://api.nuget.org/v2 Still with no luck anyone has an idea what is going wrong here,is this bug in VS 2019 Version 16.7?
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have VS 2019 16.7.0 and my nuget targets https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json (nuget v3 is there already for like 3 years) so it might be that nuget was unavailable at some point but it's definitely not a problem of VS itself as I've just tried to update few packages in my projects.

There may be other problems like the target version of your project (.Net Core project vs .Net framework package which won't work) so you might want to check that.

There is also an update to 16.7.1 so you can even try that, but this most likely won't help as the 16.7 seems to work just fine.

Comment: I have also tried 16.7.1 with no luck.can you please let me know more about (.Net Core project vs .Net framework package which won't work).

Comment: If your project targets .Net Core you can only install packages that target either .Net Core or .Net Standard, but nuget lists all of them (including older .Net Framework) even when your project won't support it. You can check what you target in project properties (right click on project => properties). Within nuget package it's listed under dependencies and you need to have in dependencies your target (.Net Framework/.Net Core) in version lower than what you target or .Net Standard (you can check which version of net. standard is compatible with your target framework on Wiki)

Answer (score 0):

I added the link below in the package source and it worked for me.

http://packages.nuget.org/v1/FeedService.svc/